Disable Collapse Behaviour in Top Bar in Compose
I am using a top bar that remains visible as I scroll through the LazyColumn, and it stays visible during scrolling. However, when the LazyColumn is scrolled to the end, the top bar collapses, which I don't want. Additionally, the top bar should have a fixed height and remain visible while scrolling through the LazyColumn, even when the user has scrolled to the end.
        val scrollBehavior = TopAppBarDefaults.enterAlwaysScrollBehavior( )


      TopAppBar(scrollBehavior = scrollBehavior,
                            title = {
                                Text(
                                    text = "Home",
                                    color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.primary,
                                    fontSize = 18.sp
                                )
                            },

     }

I could see there is possible but i don't know, how to fix it. the doc says,

    /**
     * Returns a [TopAppBarScrollBehavior]. A top app bar that is set up with this
     * [TopAppBarScrollBehavior] will immediately collapse when the content is pulled up, and will
     * immediately appear when the content is pulled down.
     *
     * @param state the state object to be used to control or observe the top app bar's scroll
     *   state. See [rememberTopAppBarState] for a state that is remembered across compositions.
     * @param canScroll a callback used to determine whether scroll events are to be handled by this
     *   [EnterAlwaysScrollBehavior]
     * @param snapAnimationSpec an optional [AnimationSpec] that defines how the top app bar snaps
     *   to either fully collapsed or fully extended state when a fling or a drag scrolled it into
     *   an intermediate position
     * @param flingAnimationSpec an optional [DecayAnimationSpec] that defined how to fling the top
     *   app bar when the user flings the app bar itself, or the content below it
     */
    @ExperimentalMaterial3Api
    @Composable
    fun enterAlwaysScrollBehavior(
        state: TopAppBarState = rememberTopAppBarState(),
        canScroll: () -> Boolean = { true },
        snapAnimationSpec: AnimationSpec<Float>? = spring(stiffness = Spring.StiffnessMediumLow),
        flingAnimationSpec: DecayAnimationSpec<Float>? = rememberSplineBasedDecay()
    ): TopAppBarScrollBehavior =
        EnterAlwaysScrollBehavior(
            state = state,
            snapAnimationSpec = snapAnimationSpec,
            flingAnimationSpec = flingAnimationSpec,
            canScroll = canScroll
        )


Im unable to reproduce the issue, The 'topappbar' is always visible (example - https://github.com/google-developer-training/basic-android-kotlin-compose-training-woof), perhaps remove scroll behaviour arguments from topappbar?

In my opinion instead of using this ->
        val scrollBehavior = TopAppBarDefaults.enterAlwaysScrollBehavior( )


as scrollbehavior , you should use this ->
val scrollBehavior = TopAppBarDefaults.pinnedScrollBehavior()

because it will pin the top bar at the top while scrolling is done. You need to implement this, and also you need to do two more things so that the body of the Scaffold(in which you are using topBar) must also be aware of the scrolling behavior. They are->

Pass the "state" to the lazyColumn.
Use "Modifier.nestedScroll(scrollBehavior.nestedScrollConnection)" to link collapsing of top bar to lazyColumn.
After that you are good to go.

The code will look like this ->
@OptIn(ExperimentalMaterial3Api::class)
@Composable
fun TopBarDemo(){
    val example = listOf("1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1",)

    val scrollBehavior = TopAppBarDefaults.pinnedScrollBehavior()//pinning the top bar while scrolling

    val lazyListState = rememberLazyListState()
    Scaffold (
        modifier = Modifier.nestedScroll(scrollBehavior.nestedScrollConnection),//Linking collapsing of top bar with lazyColumn
        topBar = {
            TopAppBar(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxWidth()
                    .height(100.dp) //To give top bar a specific height
                    .border(2.dp, Color.Black),
                scrollBehavior = scrollBehavior,title = {Text(text = "Top Bar Demo") })
        }
    ){innerPadding->
        LazyColumn(
            state = lazyListState, //To manage the state of lazyColumn while scrolling.
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxSize(),
            contentPadding = innerPadding) {
            items(example.size){index->
                Text(text = example[index])
            }
        }
    }
}

For more information regarding TopBar and it's different scroll behaviors , click here.
Please let me know if you need further explanation.
